# как убрать часть текста кнопки при изменении адаптивности

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

надо сократить содержимый текст кнопки при изменений адаптива на 320px
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Скорее всего вам придется иметь две кнопки и при адаптиве переключать их видимость.

Comment: Кнопку-то можно и одну... А вот `span` с разным текстом можно сделать два и показывать нужный при разных разрешениях...

Answer (score 1):

> надо сократить содержимый текст кнопки при изменений адаптива на 320px

Такое можно реализовать таким образом...

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 320px) {
  button span {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<button>
  Заказать
  <span>обратный звонок</span>
</button>
```